# Connect to Oracle with Entity Framework without app.config on n-tier WEB API

Tags: c#, oracle, asp.net-web-api, entity-framework-6, n-tier-architecture

Trying to use `web.config` or another method to declare a connection to Oracle using Entity Framework in an n-tier Web API application (with an EF database-first approach).

This is a Web API application with the n-tier architecture. In the past, I've tried to copy `app.config` from DAL to the `web.config` in the Web API project.

I have connected, made a new model with database designer and already have functions and a controller for displaying data from the database.

The only error I'm getting is about configuration in `app.config`

I need a way to use `web.config` or another configuration instead of the `app.config` to connect to Oracle using Entity Framework.